# Getting rid of double quotes in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to get rid of double quotes in my JSON string, this is how I am forming an array and then converting it to JSON

```
$dinnerDetails = array();
foreach ($dinners as $dinner) {
    $dinnerDetails[] = array(
        "title" => $dinner->getName(),
        "data" => $dinner->getDate()
    );
}

$dinnerDetails = json_encode($dinnerDetails);
```

Inside my view when i dump `$dinnerDetails` I see the following

```
string '[
    {
        "title": "Formal Dinner",
        "data": "Tue Apr 05 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
    },
    {
        "title": "Formal Dinner",
        "data": "Tue Apr 05 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
    },
    {
        "title": "Black Tie",
        "data": "Wed Apr 13 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
    },
    {
        "title": "Formal Dinner",
        "data": "Fri Apr 08 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
    }
]
```

and when I assign this to a JS variable this is how see it in the source

```
var dinners = [
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Formal Dinner&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Tue Apr 05 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    },
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Formal Dinner&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Tue Apr 05 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    },
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Black Tie&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Wed Apr 13 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    },
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Formal Dinner&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Fri Apr 08 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    },
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Formal Dinner&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Sat Apr 16 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    },
    {
        &quot;title&quot;: &quot;Formal Dinner&quot;,
        &quot;data&quot;: &quot;Mon Mar 28 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (PKT)&quot;
    }
];
```

I am using Symfony framework and this is how I am passing `$dinnerDetails` to view

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:admin/college:edit.html.twig', array(
    'dinners' => $dinnerDetails
));
```

and then inside twig I am assigning to js variable like this

`var dinner = jQuery.parseJSON(dinners);`

In JS i even tried doing `JSON.parse(dinners.replace("&quot;",'"'));` but this does not help.

The output that I am looking for is something like this

```
[
                    {
                        title: "All Day Event",
                        date: "Fri Apr 08 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Long Event",
                        date: "Fri Apr 08 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0500",
                    },
]
```

I will really appreciate a help here.

Comment: How do you assign `$dinnerDetails` php variable to JavaScript variable? Kindly provide that code

Comment: do you mean something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7obbbn4n/

Comment: It seems the Symfony framework is automatically treating everything you pass it as though it should be html encoded.  It's not something I'm familiar with, but you should look to see if there's an alternative `render` method that you can tell it that `dinners` or `$dinnerDetails` should be JS encoded, or perhaps unencoded, instead.

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [raw-filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) in your template. Something like this:

```
{{ dinners|raw }}
```

2nd. you have serialized a PHP-Object into a JSON-string. 
If you paste this string inside a script-block this string will be **interpreted** as JS. 
It is JS-code now, not a string anymore. You don't have to parse it; actually you cannot parse it.

```
<script> var dinner = {{ dinners|raw }}; </script>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much i should have thought of this :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller or php file use below code.

```
<?php
$arrDinnerDetails = array();
foreach ($dinners as $dinner)
{
    $arrDinnerDetails[] = array(
        "title" => $dinner->getName(),
        "data"  => $dinner->getDate()
    );
}
return $this->render('AppBundle:admin/college:edit.html.twig', array(
            'arrDinnerDetails' => $arrDinnerDetails
        ));
?>
```

Inside your view file, use below code.

```
<script>
    var strJsonDinner = JSON.stringify('<?php echo json_encode($arrDinnerDetails); ?>');
</script>
```